# "Tags" item in Catalog menu disappeared

Tags: tags

I have installed Magento 1.9.1.0 with RWD theme with sample data. But only a menu item (Tags) have disappeared from the Catalog menu in the admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 1.9.1.0 and submenu 'Tags' still inside 'Catalog'. Maybe you disabled its output `(System / Configuration / Advanced)`?

Try to open it via direct link

> {your host}index.php/admin/tag/index/key/{your key}